# Unbound variable when passing to npx

Tags: shell-script, terminal, zsh

I'm trying to create a simple script in my `package.json` file of my node project

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "db:create-migration": "echo 'Enter a filename' && read name && echo $name && npx sequelize-cli migration:generate --name $name --migrations-path db-migrations"
  }
}
```

It's to call `sequelize-cli` to create a db migration script with a provided name. It's called via the terminal like so:

```bash
npm run db:create-migration
```

When I `echo $name` just after `read`, it prints fine, but I get an `Unbound variable "name"` with the `sequelize-cli` call.

There's obviously something that eludes me, and most of the other questions are this are related to `set -u` - which I'm guessing gets set somewhere behind the scenes when running this.

I'm a unix n00b, so apologies if this is a basic question. Environment is zsh on mac

Comment: If that's the exact error message you get (capitalization and all), I wonder if it might be from `npm` instead of the shell. If it tries to expand that `$name` itself. (zsh gives `zsh: name: parameter not set`, Bash gives `bash: name: unbound variable`.) Try what happens if you run e.g. `export VAR=foo` in the shell before runing that, and have `VAR=bar; echo $VAR` in the script...

Comment: Hi @ilkkachu, apologies for the delay in replying. I changed the command to `echo 'Enter a filename' && read name && export VAR=$name && echo $VAR && npx sequelize-cli migration:generate --name $VAR --migrations-path db-migrations`, but I still get the error `Unbound variable "name"` - this time before the `echo`, so it's erroring on the `export`

Comment: no, I mean have `"scripts": { "db:create-migration": "VAR=bar; echo $VAR" }` in the file, and then run `export VAR=foo; npm run db:create-migration` from the shell

Comment: Ah ok. It echoes `bar`